# internall 500 server error with mysqli and php 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello I have two php files that are returning internal server errors 500.

Most of my files use similar code I'm not sure why these two are returning these errors.

```
POST http://52.24.192.106/friend_coords.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

http://52.24.192.106/search_friends.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

**search_friends.php:**

```
<?php 
include("db.php");
    extract($_POST);
    session_start();
    $serach_string = $_POST['searchstring'];
    if($fetch=$db->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$serach_string%'")){
       $friends=$fetch->fetch_all();
       echo json_encode($friends);
    }else{
       echo 'no results';
    }
?>
```

**friend_coords.php:**

```
<?php 
include("db.php");
    extract($_POST);
    $user_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['userid']);
    $fetch=$db->query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
    $friends_list = [];
    while ($friends=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)){
        $friend_id = $friends['friend_id'];
        $fetch=$db->query("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE user_id='$friend_id'");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch);
        array_push($friends_list, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($friends_list);
?>
```

**error:**

```
[Thu Dec 10 21:58:16 2015] [error] [client 198.179.137.231] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/html/friend_coords.php on line 6, referer: http://52.24.192.106/profile.php
[Thu Dec 10 21:58:21 2015] [error] [client 198.179.137.231] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/html/friend_coords.php on line 6, referer: http://52.24.192.106/profile.php
```

**Latest:**

Ok so I fixed all the server stuff that got messed up. Now I only get a 500 error on `search_friends.php`.

I went back to using `array()` instead of `[]` in `friend_coords.php` and that fixed that problem.

this is the search_friends.php file.

POST http://52.35.215.63/search_friends.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

**logs:**

```
[Thu Dec 10 22:22:41 2015] [error] [client 198.179.137.231] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all() in /var/www/html/search_friends.php on line 7, referer: http://52.35.215.63/profile.php
```

**db,php**

```
<?php 
include("db.php");
    extract($_POST);
    session_start();
    $serach_string = $_POST['searchstring'];
    if($fetch=$db->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$serach_string%'")){
       $friends=$fetch->fetch_all();
       echo json_encode($friends);
    }else{
       echo 'no results';
    }
?>
```

Comment: http://52.24.192.106/index.php/friend_coords.php. Are you using mod_rewrite?

Comment: The site loads a login screen if `index.php` is added to the url. Are you trying to remove `index.php` from you url?

Comment: all my files use db.php

Comment: I guess i'm confused. I do not get the 500 error when i visit the link with the index added.

Comment: Okay, good luck. I'm going to remove comments. You should update question so it has relevant info if issue persists. Don't forget to escape `$serach_string`.

Comment: alright chris @chris85 fixed friend_Coords but I need to fix search_friends, I updated the above information to reflect the error can you help me out?

Comment: I'm not well versed in `mysqli`. My presumption though is that you are using the OO approach where as you should be using the procedural approach you have used else where.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the second script, the error message explains the problem quite clearly. You have written code in what appears to be JavaScript or C syntax:

```
$friends_list = [];
```

This syntax is supported from version 5.5 but you clearly are running an earlier version. Try :

```
$friends_list = array();
```

Without knowing what error its producing, its hard to say why the first script is failing but presumably again its a parsing error,but there are several other issues with the code, not least the logic doesn't do what you think it does and its vulnerable to SQL injection and exfiltration (as is the first script).

Comment: 5.3.\d+ initially was being used this has been corrected to 5.5.+: I removed my comments diagnosing this because I presumed the OP would be updated (which it has).